# Read Oracle BLOB data as chunks

Tags: c#, oracle, blob, chunks

I have the following queries on fetching a BLOB data from Oracle (
I am trying to use `OracleDataReader` - .Net to read the BLOB value.):

Is it possible to read a BLOB data on Oracle database as chunks without loading the entire BLOB on to server memory? I believe `OracleDataReader.GetBytes()` will load the entire blob on server memory.

Passing a null buffer on to `GetBytes()` fetches the size of the BLOB but would that require the BLOB to be loaded on server's memory?

**What would be the optimal way to fetch the BLOB size and BLOB data as chunks without loading the entire BLOB in memory?**

Answer (score 0):

Look at [DBMS_LOB.READ](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999170)